# Есть ли жизнь после DataSet.Dispose()?

Tags: c#

Столкнулся со штукой, которая очень мне вынесла мозг.

Пример

```
class A
{
    DataSet aDs;
    void AFoo()
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.BFoo();
        aDs = b.bDs;
        b.Dispose();

        //для объекта DataSet уже выполнен Dispose,
        //но мы продолжаем работать с ним,
        ///как ни в чём не бывало
        var newrow = aDs.Tables[0].NewRow();
        FillNewRow(newrow);
        aDs.ows.Tables[0].Add(newrow);
    }
}

class B : IDisposable
{
    public DataSet bDs;
    public void BFoo()
    {
        bDs?.Dispose();
        bDs = new DataSet();
        bDataAdapter.Fill(bDs);
    }

    // IDisposable Support            
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                bDs?.Dispose();
            }
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Создали объект `B`, который создал объект `DataSet` и сохранил в публичном поле. Скопировали ссылку из этого публичного поля и вызвали `Dispose` для объекта `B`, в котором внутри вызывается, `Dispose` и для `DataSet` тоже. Но продолжаем с ним (c `DataSet`) работать, как будто ничего не вызывали. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За объяснением далеко ходить не нужно - [документация C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx).

Смотрим на наследуемые типы и видим среди них **MarshalByValueComponent**, который реализует **IDisposable**:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ComponentConverter))]
public class MarshalByValueComponent : IComponent, IDisposable, IServiceProvider
```

При этом сам `DataSet` **не** переопределяет `Dispose()`, так что вызов этого метода ничего, *по сути*, не делает. При этом высвобождаются ресурсы модуля `MarshalByValueComponent`, но на DataSet это никак не влияет.

За более "официальным" ответом можно перейти на всю ту же [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) и посмотреть DataSet.Dispose:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Может показаться, что Dispose() вообще не нужно вызывать, на эту тему есть довольно [занятное "чтиво"](http://web.archive.org/web/20100724023926/http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/247).